# What config do I need to change to allow a POST to an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have two endpoints in my API Gateway that are setup identically, and point to the same Lambda function. The only difference is that one of the endpoints is a GET and the other is a POST.

Here is my code that is calling the API endpoint.

```
    fetch('api/public/libraries/sign-out', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({
           'Accept': 'application/json',
        })
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Failed with HTTP code ' + response.status);
        }

        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error:', error);
    })
    .then(response => {
         console.log(response);
    });
```

When I set the method to GET, the request returns a success.
When I have the method as POST, I get `index.tsx:59 Error: Error: Failed with HTTP code 403`.

I have set `Allowed HTTP Methods`
 to `GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE` for the path pattern under which this API lies.

What more could be wrong? Is there perhaps some additional config I need to change to allow a POST? Or is it the Lambda function code that needs to be different when it responds to a POST? Or is it something else that might be the problem?

I'm using Node 6 as runtime environment on the Lambda. Here is the Lambda code:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    callback(null, {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            message: 'hello world'
        })
    });
};
```

Comment: What happens when you test the post function in API Gateway Console?

Comment: @BanjoObayomi: Good idea! I get: Method completed with status: 200

Comment: Ok so must be issue with your post call, is CORS enabled on the post function?

Comment: @BanjoObayomi: CORS was not enabled! I don't know if the Lambda and application are on the same domain, but it sounds reasonable that this was a problem. I choose enable CORS for the resource in the API Gateway. But unfortunately I still get the same problem. I tried invalidating the Cloud Front cache as well.

Comment: @BanjoObayomi: I realized I might need to redeploy so tried that as well, with no change in result.

Comment: hmm can you use curl -X POST API_ENDPOINT, and get a 200 if so, then something wrong with the node call, might have to try the request library

Comment: Can you make sure you URL is correct? I saw 403s when I miss the stage in my URL path.

Comment: @BanjoObayomi: I created a new cleaned up question with what I have learned from your comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52661966/can-get-but-not-post-to-a-lambda-via-api-gateway-why